# How to login to a remote SQL Server instance via IP and specify the Server name?

Tags: sql-server, replication

I'm following instructions [HERE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/enable-a-remote-publisher-at-a-distributor-sql-server-management-studio) to add a remote publisher to a Distributor server here. However, when trying to add a publisher via SQL Server Authentication I get the following error:

[image]

[THIS](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2015/09/18/sql-server-fix-replication-error-sql-server-replication-requires-the-actual-server-name-to-make-a-connection-to-the-server/) recommends checking to see the machine name and servername is the same:

```
SELECT SERVERPROPERTY(N'servername')
SELECT @@SERVERNAME
```

They are.

And there is a stack overflow question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8212032/sql-server-replication-requires-the-actual-server-name-to-make-a-connection-to-t) that recommends adding an additional connection parameter `SERVER='XXX'`. But this also doesn't work. I get the following error screen:
[image]

Both named pipes and TCP connections are enabled on both machines. And I'm able to login via the connection manager when not trying to configure publications.

So I think my question is, how can I specify a servername using SQL Server authentication as if I were logging into the server via a Windows login?

Comment: Is SQL Browser started?

Comment: eh... what is SQL Browser?

Comment: I'm not Googling that for you.

Comment: :p. Yea. I'm looking now. thanks - this is the first I've heard of it

Comment: @sp_BlitzErik. On the local machine (i.e. the SQL Server box where the Distributor Server is running), SQL Server Browser is NOT running. On the machine that I'm attempting to register as the publisher, SQL Server Browser IS running

Comment: Did you disable Windows Firewall (or add exceptions)?

Comment: The local server has a firewall running. The other server does not have the firewall running. Would I need to run SQL Server Browser on the local or host machine?

Comment: SQL Browser should be running where the server is running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that worked was to create an alias of (server name => IP address of the publisher) on the local machine on the configuration manager.

Though I suspect that this could also have been added to the windows host file on the local server

On configuration manager, I added the following:

```
Name: <@@SERVERNAME>
Server: IP address
Protocol: TCP (not sure why this isn't named pipes)
port: 1433
```